# datatables print button not appearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

a.extend])throw"Cannot extend unknown button type: "+ a.ex

Cannot for the life of me, figure out how to show the print button.

I have included these js libraries;

```
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
```

and the js to call it;

```
oTableHoliday = $("#holidayPayrollTable").dataTable({

    dom: "Bfrtip",
    buttons : [{
        extend: 'print',
        text: 'Print current page',
        exportOptions: {
            modifier: {
                page: 'current'
            }
        }
    }],
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "/AdminPayrollHolidayTable",
    "bProcessing": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bInfo": true,
    "bStateSave": true,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "iDisplayLength": 25,
    "sScrollY": "350px",
    "aoColumns": [
        {"bSortable": false, "sWidth": "14%"},
        {"bSortable": false, "sWidth": "14%"},
        {"bSortable": false, "sWidth": "14%"},
        {"bSortable": false, "sWidth": "14%"},
        {"bSortable": false, "sWidth": "14%"},
        {"bSortable": false, "sWidth": "14%"},
        {"bSortable": false, "sWidth": "14%"}
    ],
    "columnDefs": [{className: "center", "targets": [ 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 ]}],
    "fnServerData": function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback)
    {
        aoData.push({"name": "date", "value": comDate});

        $.getJSON(sSource, aoData, function(json)
        {
            fnCallback(json);
        });
    }
}),
```

Does it look like this should work? I don't get how the print stuff can't be found.

Comment: You need to add buttons CSS as well.

Comment: An additional CSS definition? It seems from the docs that the CSS is all handled provided you included - buttons.dataTables.min.css

Comment: You are right, I read it as dataTables.min.css.  There has been +100 similar questions. They all end up with OP have forgotten to include files, include the wrong files, include files in the wrong order or have an obscure error somewhere else, causing the dataTable not to be initialised at all.  It is never ever because something is wrong with dataTables, or buttons not show up due to some malfunction.  In this case you probably have a cache issue and some errors in the console you forget to mention, the code works fine using the includes you describe -> **http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/945/**

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'print' of undefined
    at m._resolveExtends (dataTables.buttons.min.js:17)
    at m._expandButton (dataTables.buttons.min.js:12)
    at m.add (dataTables.buttons.min.js:7)
    at m._constructor (dataTables.buttons.min.js:10)
    at new m (dataTables.buttons.min.js:6)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (dataTables.buttons.min.js:36)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDocument.r.handle (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:3)
    at Object.trigger (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:3)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:3)

Comment: and;

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'print' of undefined
    at buttons.print.min.js:2
    at buttons.print.min.js:1
    at buttons.print.min.js:1

Comment: it's weird, this does seem like a library inclusion error, but I've done everything that was asked apart from including the base datatables CSS file. Is that why?

Comment: Check if the included files is loaded at all. `Cannot set property 'print' of undefined` strongly indicates they are not. If you are using chrome/chromium check if the files is loaded on the network tab, disable cache on the same tab.  As mentioned, I believe this could be a cache problem. Or perhaps some files is excluded by something like privacy badger, or an ad-blocker.

Comment: make sure your .buttons is loaded before your .print files

Comment: fairly sure this is a versioning error, running jquery 1.11.1, and the examples seem to use 1.11.3. Is this going to be the issue? I can't change the jquery version as the rest of the site will break (tried it), also one of the errors seems to be css related, can't find class 'buttons-print'